# X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Хотел узнать в чём смысл использования такого хедера при AJAX запросе ?

Прочитал что он может предотвратить CSRF атаки, не пойму как..

Как он влияет на безопасность ?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/134150/ - как раз по вопросу

Comment: @Komodosh - Не понятно как влияет на безопасность..Ссылку не нашол полезной.

Comment: Он не влияет на безопасность. Он просто уточняет данные о запросе для сервера, чтобы предоставить тому возможность разделять запросы по типам.

Comment: https://andrepetukhov.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/csrf-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-x-requested-with/ 

Ну вот я о том же..